# How to have http wire logging in Play 2

Tags: playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1

I want to log each HTTP request and response (for debugging/development) within play 2 (2.0 for now, but I'am willing to switch to 2.X once available; Preferred language is Scala).

I found I can use [onRouteRequest](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.3/ScalaInterceptors) to get hold of the requestHeader, but this misses the body.

[ActionComposition](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.3/ScalaActionsComposition) may be an alternative, but this also does not seem to be the plain request.

Getting hold of the HTTP Response seems to be even more complicated. Obviously it would be nice to customize/truncate logging based on the content-type to avoid logging of image/binary data.

Response Logging should also work with Async Results.

Comment: Even if you are in development, you can setup a HTTP frontend, and uses its logging facilities: http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/HTTPServer ?

Comment: Setting up a reverse proxy only to log whats flowing through play anyway seems wrong to me.

Comment: yeah, sure ! Anyway, I don't understand why you don't have access to the plain request with ActionComposition ?

Comment: The request Object may contain all parts (headers, method, path, body), but has clearly already been processed compared to the original request like:


>     GET / HTTP/1.1
     User-Agent: curl/7.21.4 (universal-apple-darwin11.0) libcurl/7.21.4 OpenSSL/0.9.8r zlib/1.2.5
     Host: www.google.de
     Accept: */*


Thats what I mean with "not the plain request".

Answer (score 2):

You could make use of filters (a new feature introduced in Play 2.1). Check out http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/ScalaHttpFilters at "More powerful filters"